# Fetch the Password and confirmation field of a Model object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any way to fetch the password and password_confirmation field of a Model object in Rails.? Say for example, I have an user object

```
user = User.find(1)
```

Now, I want to fetch the value of the password field like this.

```
password = user.password
confirmation = user.password_confirmation.
```

I tried this, but it is returning **nil**.

I know, this is a security issue if they allow these fields to be accessible., But, I want to fetch these values for a feature to be implemented in our application.

Comment: I guess if you are using any sort of encryption on the password then it would return nil.

Comment: yes. am using devise gem for authentication. So, 'BCrypt' encryption mechanism should be used by default. Is there any idea to fetch the values of password fields even if the encryption is used..?

Comment: @Breenho i think i answered your question, if no, feel free to comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), the only attribute related to the user's password is `encrypted_password`, it will return the `BCrypt` encrypted password. You can also read the `password_salt` User attribute.

You can see all Devise User Model attributes with: `User.column_names`

Comment: We can get the encrypted_password but we need to use AES gem to decrypt it to get the actual password. But, anyhow I got a solution from your answer.

Comment: Due to security reasons, you should **NEVER** 'decrypt' a well-encrypted password.

Comment: Cool...!! Am not gonna...  I fixed the issue with encrypted_password.

Comment: If you want to help your users (and you) to recover their password, use this: [Recoverable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Recoverable)